# Problem was solved almost accidentally by a suggestion in an answer

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer

See [SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync doesn't find anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34340828/639739), which was apparently solved (maybe not? I can't tell when it's magic) when I installed a Visual Studio extension and restarted the IDE. That extension was suggested in the accepted answer.

I commented on the answer to say this, but didn't feel this was sufficient for later visitors. I could have posted an answer and accepted it, but that wouldn't give credit where it's due. So I edited my post to announce the solution at the top. I understand that this is generally discouraged, but the only alternative that comes to mind is to edit the answer so it says something drastically different.

How should I make the solution accessible to readers from the future?

Comment: Rule of thumb: answers go in answers, not in questions.  There's nothing wrong with answering your own question -- in an answer.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom My problem with a self-answer was that I wanted to give proper credit. I'm familiar with the rule of thumb, and it was my primary reason to make this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing the solution into your question is not advisable. It is in some ways an affront to the answer posted by another user.

The best way forward here is to leave a comment explaining what aspect of their answer ended up working for you and requesting an edit in the answer to include that aspect.

Sometimes, if you want the best results, the path forward requires a little bit of waiting. You will have to give the user a day or so to see if they edit their post to include the information.

- If they do, then at that point accept their answer.
- If they do not, then there is nothing wrong with writing up the solution as your own answer with details of why it worked and accepting that since the other user was not interested in doing that.

Comment: This has the selfish benefit of punting that difficult rewrite to the answerer.

Comment: @Grault - I don't see it that way, because most users don't appreciate large or altering edits to their posts. Furthermore, those edits tend to be rolled back. Really the only option to getting a significant edit into an answer is for the answerer to do that. This is why it requires a little bit of patience. You can always be more specific in your comment about a suggested edit to make, I noticed that the comment you left was rather brief.

Comment: Well, the solution was indicated in two comments because of the sequence of events... I didn't feel I could be any more specific than the first comment, because I don't really know why the solution worked.

Comment: Perhaps a suggested comment there: *The link you gave for the suggsted code led me to install the Roslyn SDK which solved my problem. Can you include this in your answer? This was the MSDN link I used: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89 Thanks.*